# Discord.js Command to change a Variable in the Config.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Recently, I added the ability to my bot to get the color for the embeds in a file from my `config.json`. All I have to do is change it from something like: `"embedcolor": "00A950"` to `"embedcolor": "00000"` but I was wondering how I could make a command to change this variable? I guess it would work like: `-embedcolorset [HexCode]` and the bot would change the color in the config file.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) to read the content of a file and [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) to write data to a file (replacing the file if it already exists).

You can also use [`Util.resolveColor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-resolveColor) to verify the user provided color.

Make sure, you create a `config.json` file with at least an empty object (`{}`), otherwise you will receive a `SyntaxError`.

Check out the working code below:

```js
const { Client, Util } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN';
const client = new Client();
const prefix = '!';

// helper function to read the JSON file
function jsonRead(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        try {
          resolve(JSON.parse(content));
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

// helper function to write the JSON file
function jsonWrite(filePath, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(true);
    });
  });
}

client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'embedcolorset') {
    // path to the config.json file
    // mine is in the same folder as this file
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './config.json');

    // check if the provided colour is a valid one
    if (isNaN(Util.resolveColor(args[0]))) {
      return msg.channel.send('You need to provide a valid colour');
    }

    try {
      // read the file content, it's a simple object now
      const config = await jsonRead(filePath);
      // update the embedcolor property
      config.embedcolor = args[0];

      // save the file with the updated settings
      jsonWrite(filePath, config);

      msg.channel.send(`Embed colour is set to ${config.embedcolor}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is connected...');
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

[image]

Comment: amazing! it works, thanks a lot. Is there anyway to add some code to make it restart the bot? I noticed it doesn't update the bot until it has been restarted, not a big issue, but would be cool!

Comment: You're welcome. You probably don't need to restart your bot, only update the config, however, I'm not sure how you store or load it.

Comment: I have the answer to reloading it: `function requireUncached(module) { delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)]; return require(module)}.` Then every time you want to access it, do var whatever = requireUncached('./filename'); sorry for the terrible formatting, I am on mobile website

Comment: what would the "var whatever" be? and would it go into the same file as this?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros do you have any idea why suddenly now it is not working? I cannot even get the bot to respond, using the same code.